# Match exact string or first word with Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

My goal is to match first word of a string. So when you have string like "Testing line", it would return "Testing" as first word and I can do whatever I want with it. This is what I already have:

```
elm.html(elm.text().replace(/([^\s]+)/, '<span class="first-word">$1</span>'));
```

I have element with text "Demo web" and it returned "`<span class="first-word">Demo</span> web`". So this is OK.

**BUT**

I also want one exception, when part of string contains "Admin", it would return just that part. What I want to say...

Input: `Adminer helps` -> `<span class="first-word">Admin</span>er helps`

I tried this regex: `([Admin|^\s]+)` which work OK, but only for this case. It now doesn't work on everyhing else, where "Admin" is not present. Example:

Input: `Blabla date` -> `Blabla<span class="first-word"> d</span>ate`

What am I doing wrong? I want to do it just with regex, if it is possible.

Comment: Just move Admin out of the square bracket:
`/(Admin|[^\s]+)/`

Comment: @PostCrafter thanks :) But Pranav was faster with his answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex `/\bAdmin|\S+/`

```js
function replaceText(str) {
  return str.replace(/\bAdmin|\S+/, '<span class="first-word">$&</span>');
}

console.log(replaceText('Adminer help'));
console.log(replaceText('abc help'));
console.log(replaceText('test help'));
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/fK8sP6/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

**FYI :** `[Admin|^\s]+` is a "character class" that  match a single character present in the list. In your case the first match is `d` it will replace `d`. Also `^` will only works if it's in the beginning otherwise it will act as character.

Comment: @debute : glad to help